# Export Cocos2d-x project to Android project with box2d-x

Tags: box2d, cocos2d-x

I am having trouble building Cocos2d-x Project to Android Project.
In this project I use Box2D.

It's alerting:

> Taking address of temporacy [-fpermission ]

at all the lines I have used `CreateBody` function of b2World, like following:

```
mBird->setBirdBody(mPhysicalWorld->CreateBody(&mBird->getBodyDef()));
pWallDown->setWallBody(mPhysicalWorld->CreateBody(&pWallDown->getBodyDef()));
```

Sorry i don't have enought reputation to post images.

Anyone help me solve this project.

Thanks first!

Answer (score 1):

The parameter given to CreateBody should be b2BodyDef* (a pointer to a b2BodyDef). For example:

```
b2BodyDef bd;
... set values ...
world->CreateBody( &bd );
```

or...

```
b2BodyDef* bd = new b2BodyDef;
... set values ...
world->CreateBody( bd );
```

Your code is trying to pass the address of the return value of a function, which doesn't really make sense. If you want to store the body definition in the 'bird' class and make a getter function for it, you could return a pointer to the definition, like this:

```
// Bird class stores body definition as member
class Bird {
    b2BodyDef m_bodyDef;
    b2BodyDef* getBodyDef() { return &m_bodyDef; }
};

// Use like this
mBird->setBirdBody( mPhysicalWorld->CreateBody( mBird->getBodyDef() ));
```